How do I set up a connection to the NetSuite API in Python?
Does anyone have experience connecting to the NetSuite API?
I have followed the documentation, created new role with API access with my admin user account, enabled REST API features, created tokens and keys, still getting 401 error when trying to connect in my Python code. Using PyCharm as IDE.
Here is my code -
import requests
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1

# Replace these with your actual NetSuite credentials
account_id = 'my_account_id'
consumer_key = 'my_consumer_key'
consumer_secret = 'my_consumer_secret'
token = 'my_token '
token_secret = 'my_token_secret'

url = f'https://{account_id}.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/customer'
auth = OAuth1(consumer_key, consumer_secret, token, token_secret, signature_method='HMAC-SHA256')
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

response = requests.get(url, auth=auth, headers=headers)
if response.status_code == 200:
    print(response.json())
else:
    print(f"Error: {response.status_code} - {response.json()}")

Error -
C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python313\\python.exe C:\\Users\\username\\PycharmProjects\\NetSuiteAPI\\netsuite_integration.py 

Error: 401 - {'type': 'https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#section-15.5.2', 'title': 'Unauthorized', 'status': 401, 'o:errorDetails': \[{'detail': 'Invalid login attempt.', 'o:errorCode': 'INVALID_LOGIN_ATTEMPT'}\]}

Process finished with exit code 0

